# Connector config contains no connector type

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use [JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc) to connect to a PostgreSQL database on my cluster (the database is not directly managed by the cluster).

I've been calling the Kafka Connect with the following command:

```
connect-standalone.sh worker.properties jdbc-connector.properties
```

This is the content of the `worker.properties`file:

```
class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
name=test-postgres-1
tasks.max=1

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/home/user/offest
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://database-server.url:port/database?user=user&password=password
```

And this are the content of the `jdbc-connector.properties`:

```
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-postgres-jdbc-
```

When I try to launch the connector with the above command it crashes with the following error:

```
[2018-04-16 11:39:08,164] ERROR Failed to create job for jdbc.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:88)
[2018-04-16 11:39:08,166] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:99)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector config {mode=incrementing, incrementing.column.name=pdv, topic.prefix=test-postgres-jdbc-} contains no connector type
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:96)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector config {mode=incrementing, incrementing.column.name=id, topic.prefix=test-postgres-jdbc-} contains no connector type
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:158)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:93)
```

After noting that the connector causing the error displayed only informations from `jdbc-connector.properties` I've tried merging the two files together, but then the command terminates abruptly (without creating a topic or an offset file) with the following output:

```
[SLF4J infos...]
[2018-04-16 11:48:54,620] INFO Usage: ConnectStandalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties ...] (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:59)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have most of those properties in the `jdbc-connector.properties`, not the `worker.properties`. See https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_config_options.html for a full list of config options that go in the connector configuration (`jdbc-connector.properties` in your example).

Try this:

- `worker.properties`:

  ```
  internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
  internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

  offset.storage.file.filename=/home/user/offest
  value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  ```
- `jdbc-connector.properties`:

  ```
  class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
  name=test-postgres-1
  tasks.max=1

  mode=incrementing
  incrementing.column.name=id
  topic.prefix=test-postgres-jdbc-

  connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://database-server.url:port/database?user=user&password=password
  ```

You can see some more examples with Kafka Connect here:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using source properties as a **.JSON** file later I changed it to a **.property** file and worked.If you already using **.property** file check the below things also

1. Ensure **plugin.path** is set correct in the **connect-standalone/connect-distribured** property file. If you have multiple folder put them comma separated.
2. Ensure java version compatibility
3. Ensure 'kafka connect' and 'connector plugin' compatibility.